# Calculate Time and Cost Using Values From Next Row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

Consider the following data showing the time it takes for engineers to travel to a job. The ChargeBand column shows the various rates charged at different hours of the day. Many engineers can attend one job.

[image]

I want to be able to cap the travel time for each engineer to one hour. So even if it takes longer than an hour to travel, the maximum to be paid is one hour travel cost, no more. This is fine and I can do this when the travel time is contained within one charge band using this `CASE` statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN NumberOfHours > 1.0 AND CallIDStartDate >= '2019-11-01' Then cast((1 * isnull(x.Rate,1)) as 
decimal(20,7))
ELSE cast((NumberOfHours * isnull(x.Rate,1)) as decimal(20,7))
END as LabourCost
```

However the problem is when an hour travel straddles 2 charge bands. This is the issue I am unable to resolve and would like help with. In the first two rows for example on Monday, the engineer travel from 07.46 til 09.41 but his travel cost should be capped at 8.46. So the first 14 mins are charged at 46.62 and the remaining 44 mins at 37.67. How do I do this?

The multiple tuesday entries signify multiple engineers attending. The challenge is also to identify two rows for each engineer as being the 07.46/44 and 08:00 StartTimes and cap the travel charge for one hour as per the Monday example.

I thought to partition the table by day so it was apparent that any StartTime less than the value in the previous row belongs to a different engineer attending the same job but this doesn't help with the calculation itself.

I also thought to use the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions to calculate the time or charge from the following row value, and perhaps the answer is with them, but I don't know how to apply in the code.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with CTE and LEAD function. This example works if you have two records per employee for each workday

```
with cte as(
select employeeid, weekday, starttime, finishtime, chargeband, rate firstrate,
lead(starttime,1) over(partition by employeeid, weekday order by starttime) nextstarttime,
lead(finishtime,1) over(partition by  employeeid, weekday order by starttime) nextfinishtime,
lead(rate,1) over(partition by  employeeid, weekday order by starttime) nextrate
from ratetable) 
select employeeid, weekday, case when firsttime>= 1 then firstrate
       else firsttime*firstrate+ (case when secondtime>1 then 1-firsttime else secondtime-firsttime end)*nextrate end
from(
select employeeid, weekday, DATEDIFF(second, starttime, finishtime) / 3600.0 firsttime ,firstrate,
       DATEDIFF(second, nextstarttime, nextfinishtime) / 3600.0 secondtime,nextrate
from cte where nextstarttime is not null) x
```

Comment: I think this might work but two things: a) I don;t have an employeeID, this would have to be dynamically identified as part of the code and b) The sample CASE statement in my question is part of a series of embedded CTEs - how to incorporate?

Comment: I'd be looking to partition the table by the two sets of startTime blocks as a pseudo EmployeeID. The reason for no EmployeeID is we are not interested in the employee themselves, more the job. That is the entity

Comment: @SSingh how you will identify two sets belong to one employee? are there any additional columns exists?

Comment: Mupalla That is the other challenge I am working on. I thought to partition by workday and startime. I am investigating if I can go back and link to an employee ID and bring it back thourgh the various CTEs

Comment: thats the good idea. find out a way to get employeeid attached to each record. all the best!

Comment: @KrishnaMupalla Could the Lead() function not be used to partition the table by starttime when the time in one row is less than the previous one? So when a row is 8:00 and the StarTime in the next row is 07.44/46 do the partition there?

Comment: what is the end result you are expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204345/discussion-between-ssingh-and-krishna-muppalla).